# Ubuntu 12.10 - where are block devices of whole disk /dev/sda /dev/sdb

Tags: 12.10, fdisk

I have server in OVH with newest Ubuntu 12.10, but where are block devices of whole disk?

```
root@ns:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          222G  2.4G  208G   2% /
/dev/root       222G  2.4G  208G   2% /
none            3.2G  252K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md1        495M   25M  445M   6% /boot
root@ns:~# fdisk /dev/sd
sda1  sda2  sda3  sdb1  sdb2  sdb3  
root@ns:~# fdisk /dev/sda
fdisk: unable to open /dev/sda: No such file or directory
```

On the same server with Ubuntu 12.04 I have normal `/dev/sda` and `sdb` device.

Best Regards,

Konrad Dudek

Answer (score 3):

You should open a ticket at OVH.

As a workaround:

- mknod /dev/sda b 8 0
- mknod /dev/sdb b 8 16

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

That should show all of the block devices that fdisk knows about.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/x4VnBFbz)
Of course it shows only my RAID devices, but I want to know where are disk devices of RAID (not only sda1, sdb1 etc.)

Comment: I think the  OP s interested in accessing it raw.

Comment: [update-grub2](http://pastebin.com/mVFrrkEf) doesn't work correctly too.

Comment: maybe: 1) run lscpi to find RAID model 2) Find out what command needs to be run (depending on RAID model) to get the model number or serial numbers of hdd's. 3) run hdparm -i /dev/$device, to figure out which device is which.  <--- Thats a long-shot, but might be worth a try.